# Mapping a dictionary to a vector to get a set of indexed vectors

Tags: python, dictionary, vector

I have the following vector of length 200 which contains a list of reference clips as follows:

```
clips_reference_name=['v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c01',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c02',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c03',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c04',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c05',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g09_c01',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g09_c02',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g09_c03',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g09_c04',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g09_c05',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g09_c06',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g09_c07',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g10_c01',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g10_c02',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g10_c03',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g10_c04',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g10_c05',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g11_c01',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g11_c02',
 'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g11_c03',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g08_c01',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g08_c02',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g08_c03',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g08_c04',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g09_c01',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g09_c02',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g09_c03',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g09_c04',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g10_c01',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g10_c02',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g10_c03',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g10_c04',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g11_c01',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g11_c02',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g11_c03',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g11_c04',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g12_c01',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g12_c02',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g12_c03',
 'v_ApplyLipstick_g12_c04',
 'v_Archery_g08_c01',
 'v_Archery_g08_c02',
 'v_Archery_g08_c03',
 'v_Archery_g08_c04',
 'v_Archery_g08_c05',
 'v_Archery_g09_c01',
 'v_Archery_g09_c02',
 'v_Archery_g09_c03',
 'v_Archery_g09_c04',
 'v_Archery_g09_c05',
 'v_Archery_g09_c06',
 'v_Archery_g09_c07',
 'v_Archery_g10_c01',
 'v_Archery_g10_c02',
 'v_Archery_g10_c03',
 'v_Archery_g10_c04',
 'v_Archery_g10_c05',
 'v_Archery_g10_c06',
 'v_Archery_g10_c07',
 'v_Archery_g11_c01',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g08_c01',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g08_c02',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g08_c03',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g08_c04',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g09_c01',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g09_c02',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g09_c03',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g09_c04',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g09_c05',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g09_c06',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g10_c01',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g10_c02',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g10_c03',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g10_c04',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g10_c05',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g11_c01',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g11_c02',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g11_c03',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g11_c04',
 'v_BabyCrawling_g12_c01',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g08_c01',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g08_c02',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g08_c03',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g08_c04',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g09_c01',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g09_c02',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g09_c03',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g09_c04',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g10_c01',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g10_c02',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g10_c03',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g10_c04',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g11_c01',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g11_c02',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g11_c03',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g11_c04',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g12_c01',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g12_c02',
 'v_BalanceBeam_g12_c03',
 'v_BandMarching_g08_c01',
 'v_BandMarching_g08_c02',
 'v_BandMarching_g08_c03',
 'v_BandMarching_g08_c04',
 'v_BandMarching_g08_c05',
 'v_BandMarching_g08_c06',
 'v_BandMarching_g08_c07',
 'v_BandMarching_g09_c01',
 'v_BandMarching_g09_c02',
 'v_BandMarching_g09_c03',
 'v_BandMarching_g09_c04',
 'v_BandMarching_g09_c05',
 'v_BandMarching_g09_c06',
 'v_BandMarching_g09_c07',
 'v_BandMarching_g10_c01',
 'v_BandMarching_g10_c02',
 'v_BandMarching_g10_c03',
 'v_BandMarching_g10_c04',
 'v_BandMarching_g10_c05',
 'v_BandMarching_g10_c06',
 'v_BandMarching_g10_c07',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g08_c01',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g08_c02',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g08_c03',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g08_c04',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g08_c05',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g08_c06',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g08_c07',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g09_c01',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g09_c02',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g09_c03',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g09_c04',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g09_c05',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g09_c06',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g09_c07',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g10_c01',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g10_c02',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g10_c03',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g10_c04',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g10_c05',
 'v_BaseballPitch_g11_c01',
 'v_Basketball_g08_c01',
 'v_Basketball_g08_c02',
 'v_Basketball_g08_c03',
 'v_Basketball_g08_c04',
 'v_Basketball_g09_c01',
 'v_Basketball_g09_c02',
 'v_Basketball_g09_c03',
 'v_Basketball_g09_c04',
 'v_Basketball_g09_c05',
 'v_Basketball_g10_c01',
 'v_Basketball_g10_c02',
 'v_Basketball_g10_c03',
 'v_Basketball_g10_c04',
 'v_Basketball_g10_c05',
 'v_Basketball_g11_c01',
 'v_Basketball_g11_c02',
 'v_Basketball_g11_c03',
 'v_Basketball_g11_c04',
 'v_Basketball_g11_c05',
 'v_Basketball_g12_c01',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g08_c01',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g08_c02',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g08_c03',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g08_c04',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g08_c05',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g09_c01',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g09_c02',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g09_c03',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g09_c04',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g09_c05',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g10_c01',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g10_c02',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g10_c03',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g10_c04',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g10_c05',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g11_c01',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g11_c02',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g11_c03',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g11_c04',
 'v_BasketballDunk_g11_c05',
 'v_BenchPress_g08_c01',
 'v_BenchPress_g08_c02',
 'v_BenchPress_g08_c03',
 'v_BenchPress_g08_c04',
 'v_BenchPress_g08_c05',
 'v_BenchPress_g08_c06',
 'v_BenchPress_g08_c07',
 'v_BenchPress_g09_c01',
 'v_BenchPress_g09_c02',
 'v_BenchPress_g09_c03',
 'v_BenchPress_g09_c04',
 'v_BenchPress_g09_c05',
 'v_BenchPress_g09_c06',
 'v_BenchPress_g09_c07',
 'v_BenchPress_g10_c01',
 'v_BenchPress_g10_c02',
 'v_BenchPress_g10_c03',
 'v_BenchPress_g10_c04',
 'v_BenchPress_g11_c01',
 'v_BenchPress_g11_c02']
```

Each clip reference name is associated with a set of images. For instance:
the first reference in `clips_reference_name`. `'v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c01'`, is
associated with a set of images (300 images for this example), called `labels` in the following code:

```
v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c01.**0001**.jpeg, ..., v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c01.**0300**.jpeg,
```

The number of images for each reference name varies from one image to another.

I have a dictionary of frames (image names) and their values are as follow:

```
dataset= dict(zip(labels, frames))
```

with `labels` being a list with values like this:

```
v_BasketballDunk_g08_c04_0018.jpeg
v_BandMarching_g10_c05_0097.jpeg
v_BabyCrawling_g11_c01_0010.jpeg
v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g09_c04_0148.jpeg
v_Archery_g08_c01_0008.jpeg
v_BalanceBeam_g11_c02_0058.jpeg
v_BaseballPitch_g09_c05_0002.jpeg
v_ApplyLipstick_g08_c02_0044.jpeg
v_Basketball_g11_c01_0062.jpeg
v_BenchPress_g11_c02_0012.jpeg
```

and frames are 1-D vector of 2048 values.

For instance: the first item of the dictionary created from `(labels, frames)` is as follows:

```
{'v_BasketballDunk_g08_c02_0053.jpeg':
    array([ 0.88717347,  0.51302141,  0.87405699, ...,  0.41013849,
            0.38836521,  0.37444678], dtype=float32), .....}
```

**What I want to get ?**

Since I have 200 item in **`clips_reference_name`** I would like to get 200 vectors corresponding to each item as follow:

```
vector-labels_v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c02 = [v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c02_0001.jpeg,
                                          v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c02_0002.jpeg ,
                                          ...,
                                          v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c02_0300.jpeg]
 vector-frme-values_v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g08_c02 = [[0.47,...,0.98], ..., [0.17,...,0.45]]

 vector_labels-v_BabyCrawling_g09_c02 = [v_BabyCrawling_g09_c02_0001.jpeg,
                                         v_BabyCrawling_g09_c02_0002.jpeg,
                                         ...,
                                         v_BabyCrawling_g09_c02_0248.jpeg]
 vector-frme-values_v_BabyCrawling_g09_c02 = [[0.77,...,0.28], ..., [0.18,...,0.17]]
```

We look for each clip reference name and look for its corresponding images:
`clips_reference_name+'_0001'.png, clips_reference_name+'_0002'.png  ...` and append them to the same vector.

So, at the end I get 200 vectors each representing the images  names of the clip reference name.

**What I failed to do ?**

I get stuck at creating 2*200 vectors (then number of items per vector varies in term of the number of the images that describes the clip reference name).

How to name each vector with its clip reference name. Vectors take integer indexes and not string.

I found that doing a dictionary where the key represents the clip reference name and the values for each clip reference name is the set of images associated with each clip reference name. Hence, for each key we have multiple values (a set of labels ans a set of frame values (1-D vector of 2048 for each label) which becomes difficult to manipulate.

Comment: Looks like an X-Y problem. If you need to index by string, then you need a dictionary and not a list, but per you requirements it is not evident that you need any of them. That's the hard part in development:you must first specify what you need, write down (in text or modeling language) the general design, focus on the algorythms on parts that require it and only them start to code. I'm sorry, but your question looks unclear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you are then trying to group labels and frames by their reference name, that corresponds to the first part of the label name (until the second-last `_`).

You can then create dictionaries for these two groups.

```
grouped_labels = {}
grouped_frames = {}
```

Then populate then with the 'group key', as I described above.

```
for label, frames in dataset.items():
    key = label.rsplit('_', 1)[0]
    grouped_labels.setdefault(key, []).append(label)
    grouped_frames.setdefault(key, []).append(frames)
```

Finally, you can then easily get a group's labels and frames by accessing:

```
for crn in clips_reference_name:
    crn_labels = grouped_labels.get(crn, [])
    crn_frames = grouped_frames.get(crn, [])
    # do something with group's labels and frames...
```

Comment: Thank you @grovina for your answer. l'm not sure to understand your third bloc code (group's labels and frames), when l run the second for loop (crn in clips_reference_name) l get empty crn_labels and empty crn_frames !

Comment: try `print(list(grouped_labels))` or `print(list(grouped_frames))` to see the keys that were created, are they coherent with what you expected?

Comment: Yes, they are coherent

Comment: But     crn_labels = grouped_labels.get(crn, [])
    crn_frames = grouped_frames.get(crn, []) return empty vectors

Comment: That's probably because the key `crn` is not in `grouped_*`. You can iterate the dict like `for group, label in grouped_labels.items():` for example (analogous for frames).